# How can I get event's creator from a calendar?

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to get the creator of an event in a shared calendar using google api. Do you have any clue how to do it, I ran out of option (or I didnt enought read the documentation )

Answer (score 0):

The google clanedar api has a method called events.get which returns an  [event response](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)

This response contains the information about the event and some of that information is about the creator of the event

```
"creator": {
    "id": string,
    "email": string,
    "displayName": string,
    "self": boolean
  },
```

I recomend you start with the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php)  this will show you how to get a list of all the events moving on to getting information about the event itself will be your next step.